# Persist JMX beans w/wo jolokia?

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, jolokia

We are using jolokia inside tomcat as a REST interface for JMX beans, which makes querying JMX data like CPU or RAM very easy.
Now, our customer wishes to query data in the past, which would require to store the JMX data to a kind of database.
Before implementing from scratch: Is there some existing solution to persist JMX data? Either using jolokia or not.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTSDB persists time series data efficiently](http://opentsdb.net/overview.html).